# I need to divide the last 3 non blank cells by the first 3 non blank cells

Tags: excel-2010, nonblank

In my EXCEL 2010 spreadsheet I am dividing the sum of the last three weeks total hours in a YTD format by the first three weeks total hours, the date of which can vary by the open date. I am having to update my formula weekly for close to 100 different columns, so would like something that automatically selects the last three non zeros cells (note these cells have a formula that keeps them blank until my 'copy paste' page gets data for the date range) and divides the last three non zero cells by the first three non zero cells.

```
10/28/2012       786     
11/4/2012        771        
11/11/2012       822           
11/18/2012       774            
11/25/2012       708        
12/2/2012        849        
12/9/2012        816       
12/16/2012       779        
12/23/2012                
12/30/2012                
YTD last 3 wks vs. 1st 3wks 195%
```

The above is a very small section of the 'Hours Summary' spreadsheet for 1 owner. For many owners the first three weeks will not begin at the beginning of the year. I have done lots of research over several months, but have never found anything that works. Thank you in advance for any advice or tips!

Comment: Are you looking for a function for Excel?

Comment: please, as pointed by Charx, add a tag with the application being used

Comment: Yes, I am and thank you, I added a tag for excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the spreadsheet to be dynamic, I'm not sure it's possible without extensive use of LOOKUP tables - extensive enough to be more trouble than it's worth. However, if you're at all familiar with object-oriented programming (insofar as VBA fits that label), you might try to write a script in the macro suite. It's very thorough, and much more full-featured than you might think. Recording a macro, performing a number of tasks, and examining the resulting code is how I learned the language.

Comment: I'm great with basic formulas, "ifs" "ands" and the such, but I am not familiar with using macros unfortunately.

Comment: They're super useful. You can access the menu by activating the Macro button on the View ribbon. You can start a recording, do whatever you want, then edit the code by selecting your macro in the View Macros box and selecting Edit. Turning on relative references shows a non-absolute view of how to move freely (for instance, it'll show you "select the last row in a column" as opposed to "select cell D4." It was the first experience programming I ever had, and I loved it. Cut an eight-hour process down to thirty seconds.